SELECT clause in JPA Query Methods
In Spring JPA's Query Methods, we can specify the WHERE clause but how can I specify the SELECT clause without using the @Query annotation? What I mean is:
I have an entity User with properties ProfilePhoto profilePhoto and String email:
@Entity
class User {
    ...

    @OneToOne
    ProfilePhoto profilePhoto;
    
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    String email;
    
    ...
}

@Entity
class ProfilePhoto {
    ...
    Integer id;
    String url;
    ...
}

So using the JPA Repository's Query Methods I can make queries like this:
User findById(Integer id);
User findByEmail(String email);
User findByProfilePhoto_Id(String profilePhotoId);

But not like this:
String findEmailById(Integer id);
ProfilePhoto findProfilePhotoById(Integer id);
String findProfilePhoto_UrlById(Integer id);

This can be done using the @Query annotation but that is not so desirable for me.

You don't, you will need a query for that.

Precise what columns you want. Disclaimer, you must match all columns, but you can set your relations to fetch Lazy. If this is a performance problem, then custom queries are the only solution (if not, you won't need it)

You can also create your own repository implementation and use the entity manager to call createNativeQuery, here is an interesting link explaining the steps to do it. I already did that in my project and it worked perfectly

You can use something called 'Projections' which lets you do exactly this.
Create a separate interface :
public interface UserProjections {
    String getEmail();
}

Use this in your repository :
interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, UUID> {
       
    // Usual methods
    User findById(Integer id);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByProfilePhoto_Id(String profilePhotoId);

    // unusual method
    Collection<UserProjections> findEmailById(String id);

}

Source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html

Thank you, it is so far one of the most convincing solutions, using Project or DTO does that work, but don't you think just for retrieving a single property 'email' we had to create an entire Class or Interface, It's not a big deal Ik, so I think for now that's the only option, thank you again.

I agree, this might seem like overkill for this particular case, but for the right set of requirements (see Source for Open/Closed Projections), it does provide a pretty simple and cleaner way for SELECT queries without actually using @Query. Hope this helps! :)
